# Using existing term reference field vs. creating new ones

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have 3 content types (blogs, photos, videos) that all reference the same "topic" vocabulary.

When I add the term reference field to each content type I can either create a new field "field_blog_topic", "field_photo_topic" and "field_video_topic" for each of the types.

Or I could create a "field_topic" field for blogs and then use that existing field for the photo and video content types.

Would it make any practical difference?

Comment: If you dig, there is a very similar question with some good answers having to do with the performance impacts.  I cannot find it, though.

Comment: yeah, that would be interesting, please post if you find it

Comment: Related question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16718/fields-scalability/16733

Comment: thanks a bunch. The 2 extra tables won't make a real difference in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it would make sense to have only one field that you attach to multiple content types.

If you're using a MySQL backend then a table is created for every field you create in the UI (it's probably similar for other storage backends). If you create a single field and attach it to several different entity/bundle types then only a single table is created with the values for all entities. Fewer tables is definitely more desirable.

Also if you wanted to query the database for all nodes that are within a certain vocabulary (using `EntityFieldQuery` or even Views) then the query generated would have two less `JOIN`s to make which is just much better for performance on the whole.

I think it was the intention of the developers that fields be used in this way, there's a complicated mechanism in place for managing different instances of fields and I don't think that logic would need to exist if they weren't supposed to be used like this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's better or not, but I like to have 1 vocabulary per content type. That way, I can create 3 different term reference fields. I find it more logical, especially when it comes to creating taxonomy menus and using terms in views for each of my content types.

However, I don't know the effects on performance.