# Possible side effects when changing node type?

Tags: 7, nodes

I sometimes have uses cases where I want to be able to change the type of a node.
There is a [nodetype](http://drupal.org/project/nodetype) module that comes with a big disclaimer: "only use if you know what you are doing".

Of course I would lose any fields if they have a different name with the other type. What else could go wrong?

Would it be save to use [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7), modify the type and then use node_save()?

Comment: that's actually pretty much all the nodetype module does, it just hooks into nodeapi and changes the type on save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the content type of nodes directly in the database plenty of times and the only thing I've had to deal with is orphaned field data for nodes.

I think that this orphaned data might cause some false-positive results for certain query types (`EntityFieldQuery` springs to mind) but I can't be absolutely sure.

Instead of risk this I've always written a small script to go through the field tables in question and clear up any stagnant data after I've made the content type change.

I don't think you'll encounter any errors using `node_load()` and `node_save()` as you suggest; it would probably be wise to clear Drupal's cache once you've made the change in case anything needs to be updated there.

Comment: Thanks Clive. Your advice to "use existing" term references now make even more sense to me ;-) http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22692/using-existing-term-reference-field-vs-creating-new-ones