# Do Fields Slow Down Drupal

Tags: entities, nodes, performance

Whenever I'm trying to edit or create a content type, it always takes quite a while to load the page. Is it because I have too many existing fields and `Node Autotitle` is pulling all of them and slow Drupal down?

Comment: It could be...or it could be one of a hundred other things, it's nearly impossible to say without having access to your web server. You should profile your site (especially the node add pages) to find out where the bottlenecks are coming from. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16718/fields-scalability might also be of interest

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/token) module enabled and also if you have a lot of fields, then it'll take a lot of time for the token ui to load up. This was the problem in my site. It took me a long time to figure this out. If there is a performance hit, only when you try to edit or create a content type then it might be caused by the tokens module. It's worth checking it out.

Comment: yea I noticed that too because every time I try to use VBO, it slows down as well cuz it's loading up the tokens.