# Performance or other implications of sharing fields in Drupal 8?

Tags: entities, 8, performance

There already exists quite a popular question asking about the implications of sharing fields between node/entity types:

[What's a good balance between reusing fields versus creating new ones in the context of fields scalability?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16718/whats-a-good-balance-between-reusing-fields-versus-creating-new-ones-in-the-con)

However this only really addresses Drupal 7 and not Drupal 8.

Are there any significant differences in Drupal 8? Are there noticeable performance differences to sharing a lot of fields between node types as opposed to create a new field for each node type?

I know the question should be well defined, but it would also be interesting to know if there are any other considerations to take into account when deciding whether to share/not share fields in Drupal 8.

Comment: I think the answers there are still relevant for Drupal 8.

Comment: I agree with @mradcliffe. The only significant difference is, that in D8 you can't share fields between entities anymore. Only between bundles (content types in nodes).

Comment: @4k4 Do you have a link to the part of Drupal doc where it says "can't share fields between entities anymore.", I know that's right but can find the doc part for this case